# How do I stack two landscape pictures on top of each other with a portrait picture on the side?

Tags: php, html, image

[link to example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHG8I.jpg)

Getting the black portrait box is easy, but how do I create something like the two red boxes right on top of each other? I know one solution is to export the two landscapes with the gap as one image and put it in as a portrait but I'd prefer to not do it like that.

Comment: It's very easy for me to make the sample using css3 flexbox. Do you need me to make the HTML sample like your link ?

Comment: yes please please provide a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="main">
     <div class="flexbox">
       <div class="row"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
       </div>
       <div class="row image-wrapper">
         <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
         <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>

       </div>

     <div>
</div>

.main {
  width: 500px;

}

.flexbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

 .col {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}


.col img {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.row img {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row.image-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/stargroup0075/pen/ExjMPXK

Comment: Hey thanks for this, only problem is that the images are the wrong way round as the red boxes are ontop of the black one rather than to the side

Comment: thanks as that kind of worked but I need to learn how and what values to change to get the images at the right size, also I need my site to look like this basically

https://imgur.com/a/QMkG0Nb

do I need to do a new css for each box that's ontop of eachother?

Answer (score 1):

This is a start for you.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row div {
  width: 50%;
}

div {
  margin: 20px;
}

img {
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="first">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x800/ccc/666?text=" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this seems to be the right start but the only problem is that I already have a div style so when I add this it clashes with my code by changing the dimensions of some of my pictures that are within that div box